# does windows firewalls rules have any precedence

Tags: windows-firewall

Can we change or give any preference to one windows firewall rule over other either manually or programmatically?

Actually, I have added a firewall rule which blocks all outbound traffic. Then I have added one more firewall outbound rule with respect to an application and I could see it in the list of outbound rules but still, all traffic is blocked so I could not verify my allow outbound traffic rule which is added through code is working or not? any idea on whether we can give any preference to one over other?

Answer (score 4):

Form the below link simply answer is No.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755604(v=ws.10).aspx

In most cases, the rules used by Windows Firewall to filter unsolicited incoming traffic are a union of the Windows Firewall settings you configure using Windows Firewall in Control Panel, the netsh firewall command, local Group Policy settings, and domain-based Group Policy settings. You cannot configure ordered rules or rules that specify a precedence for specific protocols, ports, programs, or IP addresses. The only time the resultant rules are not determined by a union of all settings is when Group Policy settings conflict with settings that you configured locally through Windows Firewall in Control Panel or the netsh firewall command. In this case, the resultant rules are still determined by a union, but the domain-based Group Policy settings take precedence over any locally-configured settings (including local Group Policy settings) and the local Group Policy settings take precedence over settings configured through Windows Firewall in Control Panel and the netsh firewall command.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc755191(v=ws.10)